# How to add an image preview in Algolia search result?

Tags: html, json, algolia, searchbar

I've been trying to add an image preview to my Algolia search results. It should look something like this (from Google):

[image]

The JSON template looks like this:

```
{
"url": "my-sample-website.html",
"title": "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone",
"content": "something about this page"
"image": "https://i.gr-assets.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1474154022l/3._SY475_.jpg"
}
```

There was no problem adding the other attributes, and it was searchable... but for the image preview, I can't make it to be added to the results too.

[image]

Am I using the wrong attribute or how do I fix it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Would you mind adding your front-end code? Also, are you using InstantSearch.js or Autocomplete.js?

Comment: Hello, the problem I have is I have not much front-end code, just this: ```<div class="mx-auto px-3 col-lg-10 col-md-10" id="search"></div>```. I'm very new to it and still learning. And yes believe I'm using InstantSearch.js.